# ABP how to change abp zero table and column names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I saw that I can remove or change ABP prefix from tables that the framework creates, but I need to change the hole table name and change columns name too.

How can I do that ?

Table example: 'AbpUser' to 'Usuario'
Column example: 'UserName' to 'Nome', 'EmailAddress' to 'Email'

Also, how can I disable or delete tables that I won't need to use ?
Examples: "AbpAuditLogs", "AbpLanguages", "AbpUserClaims", etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

About your examples:

```
[Table("Usuario")]
public class User : AbpUser<User>
{
    ...
```

And

```
...

[Column("Usuario")]
public override string UserName { get; set; }

[Column("Email")]
public override string EmailAddress { get; set; }

...
```

[Code Example](https://github.com/ThinkAM/StackOverflow/blob/questions/53784472/server/src/ThinkAM.StackOverflow.Core/Authorization/Users/User.cs)

After that you create the migration and update:

```
dotnet ef migrations add [MigrationName]

dotnet ef database update
```

[Generated Migration Example](https://github.com/ThinkAM/StackOverflow/blob/questions/53784472/server/src/ThinkAM.StackOverflow.EntityFrameworkCore/Migrations/20191215083915_RenameTableAndColumnsExample.cs)

The other tables you want to disable or remove are critical to product expansion, don't do that...